# Flow with Jasmine: Assign properties and methods to `this` creates 'Cannot set Property' Error

Tags: javascript, jasmine, flowtype

I am a newbie with "Flow" and I am trying to assign an arbitrary property, e.g. `foo`, to the keyword `this`. The purpose of this is to setup my test suite environments cleanly in a `beforeEach` statement. An example would be something like:

```
// @flow

describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    this.foo = 'Hello';
  });

  it('should bar', () => {
    expect(this.foo).toBe('Hello');
  });
});
```

Flow would complain about each `this.foo` with the following:

```
Flow: property `foo`. Property not found in global object.
```

I understand that it's bad practice to inject a property to `this`, but as mentioned previously, I need to assign to do this (sorry for the pun), to set the state of my tests.

Even though I have this error, I thought my karma test would run fine. When I run my an individual karma test, I would get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. This is my karma configuration setup.

```
module.exports = function configSettings(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      {pattern: 'test/**/*.js', watched: false},
    ],

    exclude: [],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
    },

    webpack: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['env'],
                plugins: ['transform-flow-strip-types']
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true,
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // start these browsers
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['ChromeCanary'],

    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,
  });
};
```

Comment: Arrow functions don't have `this`. Try using a regular function.

Comment: Wow, this works :). But, is there a way to do this with arrow functions? The Airbnb style guide complains about using unamed function expressions.